# Get Customer Resource Id with Multi Tenant OAuth on Microsoft Dynamics

Tags: oauth-2.0, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

I want our my users who are using online Microsoft dynamics to give us access to their account through OAuth2. To be clear, my users live in their own tenants and NOT part of my tenant.

So I registered an Azure AD application and made it multi-tenant but the authorize URL required the resource id which is the exact customer URL on MS Dynamics. like

`https://{orgid}.crm.dynamics.com`

but I do not want the user to enter their URL manually. I want to automatically figure out their resource id during the OAuth process and complete the process.

how can I do so?

Btw, I am not using C# and I would appreciate it if the HTTP calls could be provided.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I have been working/wrestling with some multi-tenant web apps that need to access D365 via OAuth2. While I do not claim to have mastered it, I have gotten a few such apps working.

Here are some thoughts for you:

I have not attempted to put the tenantId into the CRM url. To construct the CRM url I use the org "url name", which you can get using the below code.

This code assumes that you've put the base URL into the `appSettings` node of the `web.config`:
`<add key="ida:OrganizationHostName" value="https://{0}.crm.dynamics.com" />`

Then this code might should help you along:

```
private string getOrgName(string user)
{
    var a = user.IndexOf('@');
    var b = user.IndexOf('.');
    return user.Substring(a + 1, b - (a + 1));
}

var signedInUserID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
var tenantID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;
var userObjectID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
var OrganizationHostName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:OrganizationHostName"];

var organizationName = getOrgName(User.Identity.Name);
var resource = string.Format(OrganizationHostName, organizationName);
```

Where I have seen the tenant Id used is when establishing the auth context
`var authContext = new AuthenticationContext($"https://login.windows.net/{tenantID}");`

As shown above you can get it from the `ClaimsPrincipal`, but I think my apps are all now using `https://login.windows.net/common` rather than appending the tenantId.

If you want to get fancy you can query the Discovery service to see what orgs a user has access to. For me, [Colin Vermander's article](http://colinvermander.com/2017/01/19/calling-the-dynamics-global-discovery-service/) was the key to getting that working.

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing your experience Aron. I actually meant to say org id. I fixed that. I am also using  https://login.windows.net/common too.  Colin Vermander's article seems to be the key. I am going to check it out and report. many thanks

Comment: I am getting Authorization has been denied for this request. Following the exact sequence of the blog. So the valid token that I am getting through OAuth exchange for the discovery service does not work on the discovery service.  I am using a Global Admin to authenticate with oauth.  Any what is going on idea?

Comment: Hi @Aron. With the article, I'm now able to authenticate a user via OAuth2 with the resource "https://disco.crm.dynamics.com/" when fetching an authorization code, and then use the discovery service to get a user's ApiUrl. I can then re-authenticate the user with the ApiUrl as the resource, which provides access to the user's Dynamics Dataverse. But... I don't see how this is a practical solution. Since the resource is passed in the OAuth authorization step, this requires the user to go through the login process twice (i.e., the full OAuth Authorization Code flow). Or am I missing something?